# Google authentication does not work on my html/js code

Tags: javascript, html, django, google-oauth

I am building a web application with html/js and I need to have a Google signing. I did everything I needed to do based on the Google OAuth 2.0 docs. this is my login page

```
{% extends "home/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content=key.com">


    <h2>Login</h2>

    {% if message %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post" id="loginForm" style="margin-left: 540px;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autofocus class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <input id="loginBTN" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" style="margin-left: 643px; border-radius: 205px; scale: 1.4; width: 200px; font-size: 23px;"></div>
    
    <div id="test" style="margin-left: 300px;">

</div>


<script>

    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("this is log");
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
        console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.

        fetch("/loginWithGoogle", {
            method:"POST",
            body: JSON.stringify("email"=profile.getEmail())
        });
      }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I already have a domain and the website is published. when I try to login with google it takes me to the google login interface and I login and then it tells me One moment, loads and closes. But when I get back to the app nothing is happening. How can I fix this?